# Java Audio Video Encoder (JAVE) Convert SWF to other video formats

Tags: java, video, flash, video-encoding

I am trying to Convert **SWF** into other video formats. Currently I am using [JAVAE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php) (Java Audio Video Encoder).
In it's documentation it says that it supports SWF encoding and decoding but I don't know which codec to use. I have tried with different codecs and below is my Java code but it throws following exception. Please let me know what wrong I am doing.

I wan to convert swf to flv or any other format

```
Exception in thread "main" it.sauronsoftware.jave.InputFormatException: I/O error occured
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.parseMultimediaInfo(Encoder.java:532)
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:840)
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:713)
    at com.jave.converter.JAVEConverter.main(JAVEConverter.java:33)
```

Code:

```
    package com.jave.converter;
    import it.sauronsoftware.jave.AudioAttributes;
    import it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder;
    import it.sauronsoftware.jave.EncodingAttributes;
    import it.sauronsoftware.jave.VideoAttributes;
    import it.sauronsoftware.jave.VideoSize;

    import java.io.File;

    public class JAVEConverter {

        public static void main(String... strings) throws Exception {
            File source = new File("C:/Users/AZ/Desktop/swf/2.swf");
            File target = new File("target.flv");
            AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
            audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
            audio.setBitRate(new Integer(64000));
            audio.setChannels(new Integer(1));
            audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(22050));
            VideoAttributes video = new VideoAttributes();
            video.setCodec("flv");
            video.setBitRate(new Integer(160000));
            video.setFrameRate(new Integer(15));
            video.setSize(new VideoSize(400, 300));
            EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
            attrs.setFormat("flv");
            attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
            attrs.setVideoAttributes(video);
            Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
            System.out.println(encoder.getSupportedDecodingFormats());
            System.out.println(encoder.getSupportedEncodingFormats());
            encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);
        }
    }
```

**Update**
Attaching an image in which it shows **swf** as supported format.
[image: JAVAE Codec]

Comment: Can you try using the `getVideoEncoders()` method for an Encoder instance.. ?

Comment: Yes it shows that it supports SWF. It returns a String[ ] of the codecs it supports and it supports SWF for both encoding and decoding.